# Use disable with model-driven form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I'm trying to use the `disabled` inside my model-driven form. I have the following form:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    val1: ['', Validators.required],
    val2: [{value:'', disabled:this.form.controls.val1.valid}]
});
```

I'm getting an error (not finding `controls` of `this.form`) probably because I'm using `this.form` inside `this.form`.

How can I fix that?

PS I've also tried to add `[disabled]='...'` inside my html but I get a warning saying I should use the formBuilder instead

Comment: hey isn't it supposed to be `val1: fb.control('', Validators.required)` and you gotta change val 2 as well ?

Comment: @Ced you can read this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-angular-2s-model-driven-forms-with-formgroup-and-formcontrol#initialize-the-form-model

Comment: it says what I said though. Dunno if I'm out of the loop. Check my answer if it's completely not what you wanted then I'll remove it

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yea you're right that the problem is because you are referencing a variable (`this.form`) when it's not initiated yet. Lucky, in your case, you don't really need to refer to the form group in your `val2` form control. Your code can be rewritten as followed:

```
let val1Control = this.formBuilder.control('', Validators.required);
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    val1: val1Control ,
    val2: [{value:'', disabled: val1Control.valid}]
});
```

However, this block only initiates the `disabled` value of val2 control without monitoring `val1Control`'s validity. To do that, you will need to subscribe to `val1Control.statusChanges`:

```
let val1Control = this.formBuilder.control('', Validators.required);
let val2Control = this.formBuilder.control({value:'', disabled: !val1Control.valid});
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  val1: val1Control,
  val2: val2Control
})

val1Control.statusChanges.subscribe((newStatus) => {
  if (val1Control.valid) {
    val2Control.enable();
  } else {
    val2Control.disable();
  }
});
```

Here's the working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kEoX2hN9UcY4yNS3B5NF

Comment: OUCH, this is super verbose... I didn't expect a `disabled` to be so complex! Anyway, it's the best solution I guess! Thanks

Comment: Lovely! Saved my time.

Comment: Helped me a lot, thank you so much! In my case (and if you want to disable every form field) `this.form.disable();` worked perfectly!

Comment: how to add multiple validator in this case? with comma-separated or in array?